# How to check the performance of an Android application using Android Studio?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-testing

How to analyze the use of resources like:

- battery
- memory
- CPU
- etc

in an application developed in the Android Studio, so I can prepare a report based on performances?

Comment: Check here
http://developer.android.com/intl/in/tools/performance/comparison.html

Comment: any tools to prepare a report?

Answer (score 4):

You can measure App performance with [Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler.html).

- It provides real-time data for your app's CPU, memory, and network
  activity.
- You can perform sample-based method tracing to time your
  code execution, capture heap dumps, view memory allocations, and
  inspect the details of network-transmitted files.

[image: Image retrieved from Android Developers page]

Answer (score 2):

After running your program there will be a tabbed pane below the android studio.You can check your performance using this..
[image]